# wave file writing from Python flask

Tags: python-3.x, wav

I have a binary data which I got it from front end . I want to write the data into a wave file using python . The code I have used

```
filename = 'myfile.wav'
output = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
output.setparams((1, 2, 44100, 0, 'NONE', 'not compressed'))
output.writeframes(audioFile)
output.close()
```

. Write is successful. But while playing I can only here noise. What is the mistake in this code

audioFile :

```
b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\x9fB\x86\x81\x01B\xf7\x81\x01B\xf2\x81\x04B\xf3\x81\x08B\x82\x84webmB\x87\x81\x04B\x85\x81\x02\x18S\x80g\x01\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x15I\xa9f\x99*\xd7\xb1\x83\x0fB@M\x80\x86ChromeWA\x86Chrome\x16T\xaek\xbf\xae\xbd\xd7\x81\x01s\xc5\x87\xdd:\xcfZ\x12\xdc\xba\x83\x81\x02\x86\x86A_OPUSc\xa2\x93OpusHead\x01\x01\x00\x00\x80\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe1\x8d\xb5\x84G;\x80\x00\x9f\x81\x01bd\x81 \x1fC\xb6u\x01\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xe7\x81\x00\xa3@\xe9\x81\x00\x00\x80{\x83?R\x0b\xe4\xc16\xf8E]\xea\xe43g\x7fM+TB\x1f\x10\xc5\xc4:8>\xdc\xbac\x82~A\xbe(\x9d\xa0k\xa8\x1eK\xef9\xc9\xf9\x8e\x87 \xb5\x0bs\x1c\n\x08\xce\xc98P\'&\'\x1b\xbf\xd3[\xec\x00\x83\x11=\x87\xd5\x10\xc9\xb1\x0b\x939\x18\xfc\xe0\x82\x07\x9d:\x16\xe5W\x88\x88\xd4\xb0k\xc8\x9e\xbc\xcd\xa9$Xk\xce\xaf2\n{\xb2\xc8\xeb\xef\xf0W`\xa3\xc8X\xb8\xc8\x0c\xa8\x8b\xfePA\x15\x83V\xcaj\xe3.\x0c(n\xd9\xf9j\x18\xc5S\x15Gd\x8dZ\x8e\xb8FX\xa4\x88@\xc2\xe0\xda}e\x08J\xd1\xdf\xb5\x8a\x0f\x05\xed\xa8\x9b-\xca:\x93\x00\x10\x874}\xf2;\x06t\xeb\x8eq\xb3\xe5\xcd*\xf1\xc7\x1b\xd5{5/2W]\xbamL$\xee\x9czPg\x17\x0bp\xbc\x95\xa3&\xa2\xe0\x1b8\xef\xf7\x07Z\x11\xbe\x11W\x0e}\x03\xa3@\xf7\x81\x00<\x80{\x83I\\)p*\x04w<*\xb73&\xfbg\xb9\x84\xad\x9c\xfd\xd5\x0b\xa5]U\xc4j\xb7\xed\xd7\x02\xcd+\x9c\x18O9\xe4D\xdd\x0c\'3\xa4t]\t/^R\x14l\x83\xb6\xc8\xac\xeeS\xf7wr\xbd\xb4\\:\x02\xee\xf5\xf6\xa1&w+\x9c\t)\'\x11\xac\xdc\x99\xc0\xc5v\xac\xd4ZAM\x1f\x065\xc82go\x07\t\xe9\x01\xbc\xab\xba\xc7\xd9\xf6\xb5\xea$\xcf\xc5(\xed\x15\xd9^D\x06\x83O\x15\xa2\xa9\xce\xf4\xdd\xa2:K\xf8\xe1\xe8z#)\xeb;\r?\xae\xe3}\xa2\xb6\xce\xe8\x04;l\x81\x844\xe1\xad\x82Nays0S\xad\xe7\'*\xed\xc7\xc4\x1eO\xaa\xd8\x86DUN\xf2~x;\x86\x8ar\xe0\xea\x08\xf2\xd4\xbe\r\xb3\x13\xa1\xe7y\x9cB\x9dg,\x97\xc5\x9c\xff\xf0!\xd4\x7f\xcc\xf0+d_\xce\xea\x06\x03b\x01\xf3\xed\x1d\xb6@\xce>a\xe3\x89\'0\xbc\xbb\x18\xcc\xc6\xf3\xaa\xc9\x86\x07\xc5\xa3A`\x81\x00x\x80{\x83cW\x02F\xbd\x0e\xae\xcc\xf1\xbf{\xfdtS\xf6\xbf\xd4\xc8bb\t\x103\x8c\x10\x075sA\xb0\xd7\x17\x90;\xfe\xbaz\xc3\x1aIS\x89~\x1c8h\xd21\xa1;\x8d\xff\x966\xd6\xbd\x93\xd3\x02\xda\x8e\xee$\x9f\x0c\xa3P\xe6o\x9aM\x16\xc1\x85\x15\xf8g\xdaw?\t\x9c|\xc3=w\x17\x83\xa0\xe8Y\xdd \xd8\xa2\xd0\xc9\xcf\xd40\xf3\x01\x93N\x11 \xfc\xe9\x9d\xbea\xea\xfb\xe2T\x08\xa7i"\x0e\x06\xe3\xba\xd4\x951\xabr\xe0\xb2\x06\x0c,\xb8\x91}\xcfd\xbe\xd4\xfd\xa1\xeb7\xee\x80hR\xaf\xdc\x05\xfaD\x8f\x8a\xe9s\xd1\x95Z80p\xe7\xdaw>\xad\x9c\\,\xb5\xc9\x15\x8c\xc0\xe8Y\xdd \xda\xa2\xd0\xc9\xcf\xd40\xed\x00\xf4A{s\x04\x9cP\x88ZT\xa0n^\x0c\x15B\xb6F(\xf1\x8f]\x13\x9b\xaef\x81\xbe\x0b\xd9\x158\x12\xa3\xc8\n\xe9h2\xe5[\xb0\x98\xdb\x94\xe2\xdd\x96/\xcb\xf3i\xae\xcfO\xfc\xf2\x17FC\x87\xf7\x9e\x7f\xa4\xaa\xd6m\xd8\xf0\xd8!\xea\xac\xc1\xa5\xc2\x8e\xe7\xd5\xb3\x8b\x85\xa6\xf8\x12\x16"L\x14I\xaa\x84uW\xf2\x92\xd7\xd40\xe6d\x97\xf1\xa5\xa4\x85\xdfB\x0f\x1e\xc3\xa0\x18\x04k\x1dRL\xc7\xd7\x02\xd9\xce^\xe9\xe1\x95!\x86\xf6\xd3\xf01\xdb\'Xnf\x89o\x8aeS`5\x05\x9c\x00\xf1\xab\x9b\xbf\xfb\xad\x80\xde\xa3A\xf9\x81\x00\xb4\x80\xfb\x83\x99\x98\x85]\xe5\xbfD\x05\xba\x8ff9W\xad\tq\x1d\xd8\xbe\xba\xe7\x1d"\xed\xc1,\x8d\xdb\xd2t\xca\xca\xec\xbe\x83\xa8\xdc9va\x8a0\xef\xdew\x87\x8f\xa0\xf7\x16Lk\x18f\xa9i\xaf(\xbaL\xfc\x00\xc6.N\xfbrm\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\xb7<<\x0e\xdf\x8aR\xfbs\x1d\x10\xff\xa2\x063\x8b\x85\xa8C\xa7\x90\x98[\x88y\xb7A\xfa\xb3$L\xca\xfe0\xce\xa8\x11lx6\x92y\xf8>\x03r\xca\xd2sj\xe6wZ\xf4\xfc\x0b\xf2\xebDC3\xf3\xc2\x0f\xb9o\xcc\x0c\x9f\xd4\xe4\x9b\x04y\xf5\x9fx\xad\x0ck,\x19V/\x90=\x99\x9225\x9c\x10\x87\xa2O\xe9\x96@\x1bX\xb9\xf6\xb1\xd2\xb8\xb5\x15\xe3ly\x11<\x93L0\xbf\xcf7\xc6V\xb89IF\x10eo\x9c\xd5\xd5`\xc0Y2\xf7n\x9f\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\xe6V\x9e\x07o\xec\xf3\xaf!\x90\xb6\x7f\xd1\x03\x19\xc5\xc2\xd5!\xd7\x1e\x8a\x8d\xa4\xac\xfa\xa1\x9c\x1em|t)\xcf\x18^\x9a/\x14\x01\xb8y\xf5\xa7\x0b\xd8\xde\x05\x00j\xf1\xe9`\xc5\xac\xb3m\xcb@\x9e\x19\n\x0f\xfc[\xbc\xad\'\x8c\xbatR\x9e\xc5=\x92\xda\xe9\x932"\xa8\xe3\x87A\xfc\x99MZ`3\x82pY\xf1\x01\xe4\x15Q\xb6\x1d\xad\xef\xb9\r\r\xc0\x8dr{a\x11J `5\xe0\x7f\xb67\x1f\xac_U3\xc8\xb6\x87\xbc\xab\xa8\x1e\x15c6\x02h6U\x82\xd4\ta`\x95-\xf1\x06\xaf\xb9\'\x1f\xb5\xb6\x87\x8c\x9c\xd6t/\x92\x0b\xc0_f\x9c\xc3\xe0\xbb7\xa33\x8a\xf2{;\x05\xa5\x88\x89\xf6\xe4t\x0c0K\xab\xd1\xca\x9f\xfc\x1a\x02e\xd5\x1c\x05\xcc\x17\xf2\x94\x94Ar\x11UI\xc8w\xc6\xe7\xb5O\x0e\x80\xa2.\xbb\x83\x1a\x81\n\x863\x0c\x85\x89\xec\x02\xd6\xe8\xec]2\xf0\x8d\xbe\x14\xb6\xed\xde\xd1\xc1\x12v\x998m\x8e\xb7\xc3H\x95\xf0\x1a!\x07\xe6\xb4\x94\x9d\xa3At\x81\x00\xf0\x80\xfb\x83zy\x06\xd8V}\xbayx\x0b\xc5B=\x88"\xac\x82\xd15G\x1c\x8fq+\x0b\xfec\xaa\xc7\x1b\xcd\x0c{\x06\xa3\x1bu\x0f\x0c\xf4\xcaY\x1d\x10k\xbd\xa5E\x93\'U\xad(?||V\xd5}(\xa9\x99\xce\x9dx\xea\x84\\G\x1f\xed\xbe%6\x01\x1c\x95a\xe2hu\x81\x03\xfb4\xb3\x1c\x07?\xe4K\x03r\x11\xa0\xc1\xd4Zt%\xf4\xf5\x89z\x14l\xfaP>Rn\x1dY;K\x97\xd9\xbf\xb4S\xbc=\xf168\x94\x84\xd3\x198\x99o\xfc\xc2\x02\x898\xd0 \r\xc2(\xb7\x8e\xdfx\x84i\xecX~\x9b6W\x1d\n\xd9\nb7/\xb5S\xb4\xc8\x87\x8b\x00\xef@\xd6\xd5\xfd8D\xb8\xcc\xb6?\xe2\x9d\xe8\x0b/\x19\xcdW|o\x0f.\x04Y\xcf\xe8\xa0!@*]\x8c`:&\x89\x02\x1fQ\xa0.\xa5\xae:\xa6W\xa1\xb3\xb3\x9ak\xcd\x1f\x11pq\x1b\xcb\x9f\xaa}\xc0T\xda\xa0\x04\x0b7,\x1a\xd6\xda\x944h\x9908a\xfb!\xac\x85\x94gWN#\xee_\r\x90\xdfv"c\xdc\x0e\xc8\xcd\x1a\xa8\x91\xa2\x16\x00h\x87\x84\xb1\x1e\x91\x88_\xad\x02\xf7\xaf`O\xc5\xccNp\xb4\xd4\xaeUU1\xaa=Vbg\x8f\xff\xa1w\xc1\xae\xc0z\x07\xaf\xf5\\\x8br\xb1\xbc\xd8\xa0\xcd\xc4\xb0\xb9\x01_\x03\xa5Y*\xbe\xa3\xc0\x12\xd1\r\xad\xcb\xc4\xfa\xaa\x08\x0c0"f\x9c\xd8\xd5\x01=ZF@\x970\xe8^\xb2\xbeh\xf1\xce\xa8\xa3A\x80\x81\x01,\x80\xfb\x83zy\xa0:\xa0M\xc9_\xec\x10\x8b\xe9\x04O\xe9!\xfd\x87\xa0-\xe6\xe5I\xc8\xb0<\xf0N\'\x94kA\xda\xea7\xec\xf7m\x87l\t\xff\x03ZN\x88=\xb1\x84\xbf)\x84_\xc4R;\xa0\x0f\x97\x89\xa7>\xf1\xae\x8c\xba\xcd\x81\x7f\x9e[\x08\xcbh\x16\x8f\x9b@O\x1bu\xf0}u/:\xa4TS\x11\x17\xa5/\x96a\x04\x14\xb5\xc2>"\xfc\x00|\x19\xf4\x98\xc5\xd2\x03\xa4\x88\xa1i7\xde\x0f\x01\xc7\xd8c\xbc\xe1i\xa0W\xfb\xd4<M@\xc4\xa9!\x1aP\xdeh\xda@oP 3}V\xcadH\xac\x99\xba}\x92\xf5p\x87\xad\xf3\x86\xee\xd9\xd2\xb6b\xf4t8\x1c\xe8\xd7\xf8=\xbf/E\x8b\xe0\x83a\x9f\xe4\xcdx\\\xee\xfa\xef\xb6\xa1\xef_\nX\x14\xef#\xf5\xcev\x94\xf8\x13Q\xfc\x1eW@\x8cT\x17\xcb\xf1\xcaV\xb4!I\xd3?\xf8\xba\xec\xa4\xb3\xae"\x14\xec\xc67)\xd6[/\xb01E\xb3v6\xad\xdb}i\x96\x0f\nn:2<\xcfF0,\xbe=\xfd]\xe6\xd6\xaf\x91q\x0f\xa9eG\xb8\xe0HZ2i\xb2z\xc80\r\xb47?\x15\xbb\x94M \xae\x82c\xc0\x0e\xffM\xed#\xdf\x9f\xe92t\x89\x9cu\xe3?\x102\x8c\x88\x9e}i\xfee{:\xc6\x962[P\xb3\x96>Q\x7f\xb8\x81\x95C\xa8u\xf6g\xb6T\x00\x11\xc6\x13u\xd0\xbe6\xf1\\G\n\'\x18]\x9f\xd9\xb4\x9a\x93\xb6\xe5\xaa\x04\x18\xc03\x0e\xe1>k>\xd9\x16\xef\x92\xcc\xbbFK\xa3A\x8a\x81\x01h\x80\xfb\x83\x83\x81\t\x0b\xa2\xa01\xa23n\xdee2\x83\xd3\xb9\x02\n\xc3Hq]zd\xb0\xdf\x91\xc6\x92\x1bU\xc6\xcc\x88T\xc6\xad\xb2\xc3\x06_\xdb\x9f\x1d\xc1U\xe7p\xf2\x95\x90\xb0\x88\x95\xb0p\n!#I\x0e\xc7\xe3\xa4+\xfbU\xc8\xa3FR\x13\r\x92TPx~\x91s8\xd4\x9a\xd1~x\xa1\xa6\x88\xf5\xbf2\xd1Z\xb1u\xde6\x92A\xd7\xe4P\xbf\xd2\x1f\xa7\x1b\xe6\xf5n\xc2\x8a\x1d\xdf-+_zd\xab\xff\xfdc\xdc\xfd\xff\x1ce\xb5\xfb\xec\x1f\x07_\xd5\x81b\x8c\x0f!3\x19k\xf1Qz!\x1f\x0e\xde\x14\x0b\x17+{\x1b\xd3\xe5\x08\x14\x8e.\xfe\x05\xe4 A\x0e\x91\x9d;A\x97\x88d\xc4\xecX\xcf.C\x1d:Iwu\x17\xf3l:\x9a\xd9:\xe6\xda\x11\xb48\xa3\x832\x83\xa5\xed\xfd\xe8\xd029\xa0\x10Fvl\xc2\x10a\xdf\\\x9b_\xe5\xe7A\xe7n\xc3\x0fx#\xf8\xd7@\xearz\x98\xf3G\x0b\xc6}\x9b\x1e\xa8ud/)\x19\xe4\xe3\xdf\xa2\x0eh\x8e\xce\x08\x08\x17\x07UE\xd5\xc5GA\xe2H\x0eYqwEVA\x12\xd3HQT\x8d\xb6r\x92\x89G\xf4\xf8T\xc2\x97\x1b)[\x9f\x90\xff\x90\xdb\x9c\x94\xd8V2\x00 \xad\xbd.D\x9f\xdeb>\x1c\xd4\x06\xca\xfc%\t\x8e\x1d\xeb\xc4J\xcb\xdd\xfc\x0b\x99\xb6yg\xcd\x0el\xb4?E>t\xa59\x86TbZ\xd0\xe8\xc2e\x1d\xc6\t\xdffQ&\xd9\xdc\x11\xb3\xe2r\xede6\x0e\xa1s*\x0b\x98\xcf\xfd\xa8\xbc\xc2-\xdc7\xa1\x1e6\xa3A\xa9\x81\x01\xa4\x80\xfb\x83\x89\x94L\x04.\xc9\xf0%\x8dt\x98p\x1b\xa6\xac3\xb1\r\xaa\xf93#E\xf2\x08\xcdC{\x9b\xf1%\x81\x82\x01\xdb\x9a\x85\x13\xce\x0b\xd8\x9dr\xf5\xb80\x84\x92f\xeb\xfa\xa2\x99^!\xeaH8\x07\xc3\x96\xabt\x04}P\xb4\xc8\xb1\x19\xde;\x99\x87\xb1\x1a\xee\xad\xddw\xcc\x1a\x8a\xe1\xdc\xdd\xa7\xd6\xbbW\xa5\xdcx\xa1\x06\x0c\x19s\xfb5\x06\x9a\x1f\xda<\xeebL\xac!\x03Y04\x17@\xae\xd9Ga\xe28t\xfc\xe1\xd4\x00$\x0e\xbc\x98X\x9a\xa0\x0c\xcf\x1f\xbc\x01\xdf\x98\xccchW\xd9k\x04\xc1W\xff\xd2\xe5pvO\xed\x9e*\xe7\x84C\xf3P\x87\x93A\xd9\xb0[\xd2\x8bg\xbf\x1b\x1a\x80\x19\x98\x0f\x03\xe3\'d\x82\x00Y\xf7s\x9f\xe4>Fy\x0c\xdc~\x1dfWTmi\xe7lq.\xcd\x9b\x1b\x80\x009\xabo\xed\xfa\xde^o\x03{\x7f\xc6H\x0bDW]EJ\x1a\xb4\x0f\x0b8zqc\'z\x8cI\xb6\xedd\x0f\x8b4\xba\x82\xb2\xab$5\xa0\x19\xef\x12;oN\xa9\x01\x11=\xe9;*@\xf8@\xaa\xfcM\xfa\x08k\xed#\x13\xe3\xc5\xb9Dt\x91\xd5|^\x1d\x01\xa9\xd7\xd4lmti\xca\x92\x8a\x9d\x82XS\x88H\xee=R?\x18y\xed\xf77\xf1\x1f\xee\x8b\xb8<\xfd\x0f\xd3\xeb\xe7\x07\xc4\x94\xe2$\xcd:\xe4\xef\x05\xf5\xd7\xf3_A8\x02\x84\xe3\xd45\x8f\x8f\xd9r\x02\x8f\xd6)\x93\xe4:q\xe6%F\xe7*\xff\xb7\xe7\x0b\x9a9;?\x80\xc6\xee\xc8\x82\xfc\x9bX\xb7\xde\xe9U\xd5\xc1\x01\x83\xde\xf3\x193pq$O\x15\x98j#o\xf31\xaa \xb1u+!\xab\x1a\xe1B\x99V\x84\x92\xa3A\x86\x81\x01\xe0\x80\xfb\x83\x7f\x80\xd9\xa6\x0b\xdb\xfbM\xfe\x12\'\xc77Z\x9e\xe0\x03\x81m\x0bO\x98\x99\xd2\xaa\xbf\xd7 -8\x13\xe8l\xbb\xec\x04\x12\xd8J\x1cI\x8a\x02\xb8U\xe1\xb6\xc3,\xc7vt\xa2\xa3xSW\xf5\n\x19U\xa9K7\xdf\xc5\x93=\x84\x93B\xda\x15)R\xd6\x00\xf0R8\xe2\xa8\xd0f\xbf0\xb7\x06b\x85\x1f\xf0\xe5N\xe5\x96\x01\xba\xad\xb9q\x1aXtR\xde\x96\x83{B\xb0\x7f@\xc9\x9c\xe6\x124P\xd8\xfaw\xfb\xd0\xda\xf5p\x04\x95\xd8\xff\x13\xd5\xa0\x8f?\x7fYg\x16gv\xc6\xfb\xf1&\xe7#\x1f\x0c\x0c%\xaemBfI\xf4\x1a\xe4\x1f\x1bi\xcb\xd35M\xfc\x92\xfd\xcd\xc3\x0c\x8d\xfc\x0f\x1cJ\xaa\xbe\xe2\xe5R\xbcW\xec1G\x8e\x94\x8c\x01\xaad\x9cYs\x94\x15\xaf\x8d\x17\x9d\xaf\xd3W\xaf\xb9\xba\xf2w+\xf3\xdf\x15\xa7:\x063+\xcc,^\xe0\xb7\xdd\xcb9\x83\x1c\xde?\xb1\xd0\xa4\x8e\x9b\xe1\x9a6\x9c\x08\xe1yO9\x8fZ\'\xb5\xbc(\x1e\x891\xcc\x96\xd9\xb6\xa6Y\xc1\x83z\x13T\xc9\x0c\xc3\x97&\xa5\x87\x08Rf\xafWM,\xd0\x07\x03:\xfb\x06k\x9b\xb9\xab0\xb2{\x06w\xe2\xf6X\xa6MQ\x1f\xfad\x1c\xf7\xcaiR\x954\xba\x9e(\xc6)\xb8\xb5o\x15Bm1\xd2\x9ds\xaeu\xb4{\xfa\xa7}\xdd\x9eq\xbb\xa4\xf3h|\x84Qj\xc3\xcc\x1f\xe5L\x0e\x160\xd8\xe3\x9c\xf52\xd9)\xe8\xc1\xd6\x18Q`X\xf72.1\xda\xd7O\xa7(_\xe1a\x9a&\x99\xc0\x12\x96\xa3A\x87\x81\x02\x1c\x80\xfb\x83\x80\x7f\xd8|\xf9\x0f\xb7\x9em\'\xb3:\x1a\xba\x1e\xfd\x86$\x1e\xbf&\xbdh/\x97d4\xa6\x0b\xec\x1a}\xf1)\xc5m\x9f@\xb1\xc2\xe3\xa6]\x83\xde\xc4\xb5@\x89\xca\x88a\x91\xa07\x94J\x8cPF\x89\xef\x86\xef\xf5\x01\xebq\xe9\x89}\xfc\x97\x88)\xadh\x8d3b(K"\xf9\xa9dx ,\xda\xd5\xbd\xa7\xebz\x87,\xdd\x07\xd9T=\x92\x89BK\x86\x9eG\x99o\x9e\xa3WQ\xb3\xe2\x04\xb0D\x1dyI\xfb\'\xfab\xaf\x8b\x98\xd8\xf5\x8c\xae1\xaf\x9cg\x07je\xa9W\x14\xc3\x028\x97}\x05\xe2\xcd\x1fe\x1a\xabjKqD"L\xae\xbd\x9f\xb1,D\xd1\xda\xf1k\xcf\xd7\xde\x9f\xfc\x16\xf4\xf4\x18es\xa8)v\xb3@\x1b\xf3\xe9Z\xab\xa1\xf5\xb1:@\xb1\xab\xa2?\x0bN5b:N\x9d\xc6\xe3\xbd\x12\xfd\xea\x82\x17,\x06m\xc3\x95\x94\x8et=\x8eD5\xe1\xf7\xaf\x85\x08\xfbW*\xbb^\x9cQ9@\xef8\x16\xa0l\xf7\xc4\x0e\xf9Y\x8b\xa5\xcb\x9b\xd6b\x84q\xd1bP\xdc\x07q\x98EGf\xe4\x8c\xa2\xc0\xa1\xb8#\x12\xa9CLd\xc9s\x7f\xd4\xef\xdf\xa8\xd3\x11\xf2&7\x86\x19,\x90\x1c^\x18\xbc\xa1\xe9\xe0\xaez`\x13\xa5\x9bE\x86\xbc\x7f\xec\x90B\xa0\xd4\xdb\x91\xad\xee\xc4m5F\xb8\xe3$o\x0e\xf78Nr\xd4vq\x9a\r\x9eT\x06\x84\x9aF\xa0\xb3\xca\x1dck&B_\xf8{\x8c\xaf\xb3\xb2`e\xf5\xb8\xa7\xedr\xe1\xeb\xaf\xb4\x8b~4\x1e\xf4\xbe\xacr\xb4\x9d\xa3A\x86\x81\x02W\x80\xfb\x83\x7f\x80\xd8\xff\xfb\x91\x85"o\xf7{v\xf9\xd7j\x1c\xd2i>\xd5\x02\x0c\xb7Z\xff\x7f\xf7\xfc\xaaP\x8a\xb8\xf7\x19\xa8|u>\\\xe8C\xd9\xbbj_\xa1\x1b\xc2xIfpb\xf3@\x08\xce\xe84\xa9n6\xcb}#\xee\xcdj\x18T}\x18p\xc0\x17\x03\xee\x00\xcc\x84\xb4\xc03\x02\xfc\xe5\x84k\xd6\x8b\xd7\' \xae\x1c\x95\x94\xfe\x0e,=\x80\xb3\n\xbe\xe5\xaeS\x99%\x19qs2X\xdc\x9d\xfb"\x0bt\x0c\xb2\x03~\x0fy\x93\x9a\xd9\xb7\xc1!^(\x04\xa3\x00B\xbd\xed_\xe0W\x82\t\x88]\xcb\x86]\xd6\xf7>\x05\x8a@\xff)>W\xe7\x90\x81\x07%<;\xe6\x8e\xbf]~l\xc8\xdcJJ\xb7\xfd\x13?\xcf\xb8\xd1\xeb\'@\xc7\x95\x9b&\xe3\xb9t\x1ay=?\xb9i*\xdc\xc3\x97C\x08\rf\xf0v\xd2\xd1\xc1|\x86\xd4Z^0\xe5E\x89>q\xf6\xa5\xfd*\x10\xfc\x04\x81\x0f\t\x13\xf9\xf0\xcd\x92\x1f\xd9\x07Xa\x8a\x95\xe6\xd6\x81\xa7h\xa5I\xbfL\x96\xd6jO\x96\x84\x99\xee\xd8T+\xa3\xbf\xcf\xa8#\xbd<\x06\x1b\x85\xc5\xcb{\xce^\xfb\x1a\'p|\x0eI\x17V)\x1e\xa1\x80\x9e\x89\xd1\x80\xee\x83\xfe\x1c\xa7w\xa4-\x10\x9e;r\x9f-\xc2\x9c<4\xab&yc@jj\x16@m\x9a !eE\x9a\x95\xab\x9f1\x17\xe5\xc0\xfa\x99!|\x98\x1c\\\xc8R\xb9\x8ap\x16x4\x07\xf5?m\x98\x8d\xca\x17\x93v\xfe\x13\x12\xd1\x0c\t\xcc\xa0ho\x87F\x97\x8b_\xb9q\xf4\x95\xa3Ar\x81\x02\x93\x80\xfb\x83\x80|\xd6\x92\xfa\x02\x05\n\xb7\xf0\x10\x8e%0\xf3\xaa\xd5\xceg\xf6\x920B\x0e>\xcb\xc2\xcf\xe4\x85\x9b\xc0\x1d\xc4\xfb\xb5A~$\x08\xa1\xc0\x0cH\xda\xde\xff\xbf\xa1\x88\x1fc\xfe\x16\x12h`u\xe8M\xbeT\xd2\x15\x19S\x0f\x91n\x1f\xe6\xd4w{\xf5\xf7M\x82\xaf\x84M\x01\xa3l\xf9\x00\x1d\xf3\xbe\xda\xe2mvhm\x98\xca\xc3n{\x8b\x07\x031\xaa\x81\xcbl\xe6\xec\xe8\x0b\x159\x82P\\\xd9B\xe0\rv\xb9?\xf1\x166\xac2\x97\xd6:E9a\x18\xd3\x1c\xf9\x96\xe4\xc6\xa4\xbc\x08!2\xe7\xf4\xc7~\xd7HDa\xa4|\xba\xc6~i!R\x08\xdd\x0f\x1b\x7fE`R)\x14\x94\x1aND\xd4;!\x8e\x89\xa1\x10\x12\x05\xf6\x94[\x9b\xfb\x91\x0f\xbc\xf2\xbf\xce\xd1\x89c\n0:58\xbaV\x9fWyyQ\xe6\xba\xea,\xab(\xe4\xd4\xc4+\xc9\x19V\xdd\x1fYE\xae\x81\xf4\x91G\xbb?\xd6mU\xa6\xdc\\-\xed\xed\t\xa9\xd3&8=\x89\xa2\xa1*H\xda(\x07\xf01\\v<\x18\xa7!{\xcav=1I\x0bi\x0e\x85m\x89\xe2\x16Ux\x0e\x98\xd7\x19f;$\xf9\r\xa7\xab;\xb4b\xd0x\xd3#\xcbK\x89\xdb\x98!\xc6\x85\xce\xde\x05\xba\xb8E\xce$]3\x14_r8\x88i\xff}\xcf\xd3\xf3\x8eJ\xb2\x14\xba\xed\xd0@\x81|\xf5\x87k\x86\xda\x97\xd1C\xb3S\x13C\xc3\x94&\x01:\xe3\xd7(\x96N\x05\x91\xa3A>\x81\x02\xcf\x80\xfb\x83lg\xd5n\x1a\xe5\xae\xad`O\x95I\x98\xaf\xb7\x99\xbfz\xa3\xef\xfbR\x0b\xe88\x8cZ\xd4Q\xe4\x92\x83\x9e\x96\xb2;\xbf\x9a\x13\x16\x12\xffJ\'\xfc,\x7f\xdcr\t\x11\xe7\x99\x03\x96E\x93\x93+p\xdb2\xaf\x89+9\xd6\x8cd_\xbc_\xd6\x7f\xae\xf2\xff@j\xbe\x01(\xe8^\xfe\xd3c\x1c\r\x8e@N\xdad\xab\xca\x80j\xd5J\x00\x0f\xdd$\xdcA\x19\x98\xca\x9fD\xf5\xc4\xd2k9\xd4\x8c\xees\xff\xd8\no\x9eN\xd6\xfb\x03t\xcb2\x0c\xf5h\x85"\x1f\xf6_\x0c\xaeS\x03a\xf3@\x03\xa8;,s\x9d\x03\x9f\xbcp\xc8p.\xbd\x87pE\xa1\xc9\t\xbf\x1d0c\xb1\xf8\r\xf7\x19\xd8Z\xce\x84\x0eC\xf3\xe9\x1b\xc3\xa24<\x96\xf8\xfcwAQ\xaa\xab]\xac\x91\x99\xd3\xad\xc7\xb8r\xf1\xf0\x96\x8e\xdc@\x0f\x03oJ\x18o|!L\xcd\xe9\xfc\xff@-\xcb;\xbe\xa5\xf2\x8f\xf4\xed\x8fv\x81i$^\x88\x9f,\xfd`\xc3\r\x1c\x9fD[$Q\xbco\xdad\x81RS\x02\xb8J\xe3\xf6z\xd2\xd3P>g\xf8X\x05nh\x92q\xf1\x8c\x85\xab6?@h\x85L;\x84\xd2\x11\xfb0?\xee\xd6\xb4\xc7\x87\x8e\xe8\xfb\xe4\x05\x98\x8b?\x1c\xf2\xc8\xa3Ad\x81\x03\x0b\x80\xfb\x83a|\x18\x8f\xbb\x8e\xad\xba\xea\xe6\x90\xc3Z\xa2\xb1\xb18\xeb\xcc\xc0\x94\x17\xeb7wd\x82\xa3\x1cB\xa37\xa0\xda\xd6\xb8\x97F\xfea\xbfZ+\x1f?G\x8e\xc6\xc9\xb1\xd9\x02p\xff[)\x8a\xaf\xfa\xd0\xc8\x0c\xef5Q\x89\x93,>\x1f\xe8a\xff\xe1!\xa7S>Q}L\xbf\x82\x9a\x1e\r\xa4\xfb\xda\xc6S\x96\x07\xcf\xbd$\xc73p\xb1\xab\xb5R\xfc\x8c\xc7\x9f\x1br\x9b\x97\x11\xe8\x8f\xd5g\xec=}\xa2\x8b\x14n\x84\xf35\xa5\xa7\x06\x17{\xe3\xb5\xf2P\xaf!\xd7\x0f \x8fU\nR\xd6\x0by\xca\xd2\xae\xb7\x9a\xe8&\xe7\x92\xd8O\x85^\xe8\xcbi\x1f\xbb\xd8\xaaA\x0f\xb0\xe1\xc2q\xc7\xf0\xad\x86\xe7\xf9\xd4\x05F\x98\xf3P~\xd7\xae\xec\xf4Y,J/&\x7f\xf9\xccm\x15\xf1\xc6\x01\x8a\xfdI\xe6\x96\xfd\xa3\xbb\x07\xac\xeb\x9a\xa1\xa3\xdf\xab@\x12\x9a\x8d\x1c\x0f\x90T\xe2\xe9\xae\x028\xe3 \x9f\xf5\x9dH\x87\x955\x83\x045#}&j\xe5O\xdcl\xfe\x08Pq"N\x90\xd5\x06~4\x8f\xc4\xb0\x17)?\x13\xc9\xbd\x00\xd4\x05e\xe4.\xda\x969\xc6U@TUV\xcc\xe9\x96\x9d\x855\xc3\xa7\xdf\x8c\x02\xee|\xa4\xd8.\x01T9\x9b\xa0\xe2\xec\xf8\x9d\xb6\x05$\xe6\xb3\xe2\x0e\xbc\xd6\x12\xcd\xda/\xda\xfe~0\x0f\xd4\xd6\xb7\x9c}r\xba\xcb\xbep+\xcf:m\xfd\xadk1\x7f,\xa3A\x83\x81\x03G\x80\xfb\x03\x15`\xffHS\x8d+j\x80\x88\xc9\xfa\xe8\xac\xe1i\x87L\xd6\x0c\xa25\x04rU=\xed\x1d\x032\xd7`W\x9d&U\xbe\xb3D\xc8\x05\xe6\x93\x8c/\xfa%[6!\x87QfQ\xd9\xc9q~\xdb\xf0\xed\xaf\xfd\xb2\x90\x89\xb8\x9d\x17\xc9k\x02\xd3\xde\xd5\xf8\xf4$\xcb\xa6\x8e\xf57P\xa3\xd0n\x93\x14\xe8;?na\xa2\x1d\xe9\xd3\x19\x0e\xb9#y\x9a\x03\xaeTLr\xb9\xb7\xd2\xf1eQ+u\xe8\x10\xf3\xe4\x01\x8e\xca%\xf9\x80T\t\x19f\xf6\x84\x9d\xc7I0b\x93\xf7\xb1\x9b\xf9R\xf8\xd1\xae\xff\xd9\xcbB_\xcfS\xee\x90\x9b\xbc\x1dmD\xb3\xed\x98\xf4\xc6\xf9Y3\x9e\x9b\xb6\x85\x05\x1dD*\x1a\xa3-\xe2*(I\xa9~e\xe0\xd6\xf7\xe3\xea\xcd\x8c\x00B\xdeg0_\x90t\xc7\xb3\xfe\xbeo\xfe\xd3Q\xc3Px\xe4\xa5\x96\xd45\xf1\xcd\x8f\xe9B\xb4IR\xed4\xcb"\x1a\xbf\xb3\'k\xbb\xf5\'\xfeD\'\x91\xd6\xc6Tx#s\x04\xfbD\x10^\x07\x10#\xda\x16\xf0\x16\xd4z\xd4r\x8feCU\xec7\xc2\xee\xdd\r\xc0\x91Q$\x03\xcf\xde\x10\x9f\x98YWS*\'/\xb7\xd04\xd9\xea\x91,0|i\xb5\x8cE\x04}\xb7\\\xa4\xef,\xfe\x876\x1f\x00\x98;\x82\xa6H\xfb.NZ\xb7\x82\xe5\x90\x93s.\n2\x8e\xa3\r\x8ckKE\xael\xbd[\xf1\xf7?\xda\x82\xc31s\xdf\x83\x00\xf3\xf0Z\xd8\x94\x90\xaa\xb6N\xe9\x11\xb4L\xf1;\xd3\xd8\xb7\xa5{\x8e\xeb\xcd\xfd+d\xa3A\x83\x81\x03\x83\x80\xfb\x03\x19\xa0\xf0b\xcaRs1\x8f2\xb5\x1bV;\xb3\xb2\xbdgA\x08sRK"\xa4\x00m\xf0V?\xf7\x90\x11"a\xb4\xbb\xcd\x94\xb3\xf4\x88\xdf\xb9/SBe\xceh\xca\xca\x1c\x86n\xbc\xf1\xa3D\r\xa02K\x16\xe3\xc0?o{\xe8^\x0bm\xef\xd8\xd5\xac\x19\x953k\x8cv,\x93y\x85\x17_\xb7\x94\xd3T\xbb\x0b=\xc3@\xf4r\xaf-I\x041\x8b\x10YDyW\xcc\xfe"!\xdb\xbf\xa5\x129G{\x9aQiX=<o\xea\x05:\xfe\xa5qp\xb9\xb6U\xcfq\xd3)]\xc3B\x97\xa6H^5\x87BA\xd8Ur\x93\x919\xa9\xc6\xc6H\x8eC\xf91\x98\x16\x7f\x8a5\x19\xb4\xa6\xc4\xe5\xd2\x8b7\xeaE\x17\x90\xd6!\xd3&K\x88\xedn\xd6\x14{\xa9\xa1D3#\x95\x1b\xec\x15\xc9\x1d,h(~[j3`\xa3\xda`\x81\x903R`\xbb\xb2\\\x19\x1e=\x0bLX\x9a\x98\xd9\x8aN\x05;]m\xad\xed\x11\xd8\xd4\xb57\xe9v\xb9\x8e\\\xb3C\x9f\xce\xab\x81\xd0\xbd\xa0\x10#\x90\x98\'T\xa1d\x1e\xb9\xe9\x05g\xcd\xdac\x80\x9b^%2\xe2\xab\x01&\x8d"%\xe5\xbe[\xbf7\xbe\xd5\xc5\xb1#I\xe5\x17\xac\x8d4\x95\xc7\xcdu\x83 j\x9e\xc0\xe5\xf0\xcb}N\xads\x0e\xb5\xab)\xce\x03\x9b\xaa\xb4y\xb9\xec\xd90\xe9\xeb\xb5I\x06\xb9*\xc7y\xfc\xa6\xec\x1f\xd8\x05#\xd9\xd7K\x0b8\xf7v\xe0\xad\xe4\x95\xac\x89\x7fo\x87H|\x04\xeey\xda\xc0Ir\xe5\xd11\x82\xa3A\xd1\x81\x03\xbf\x80\xfb\x83\x7f\x8f\x16m\x832{\x9a\xc3\xd2\xdc\x7f\xcb1\x1f\xbf\xc1\xbf\xbfx\xe9\xba\xecm\x80\x1dL\xbaC\xec\xe5\xed}\xc2\xabVYAK\xebP0\x80\xa2G}\x05\xce\xed@\xad\x04\t\xee \xb7\xe7CG\x87\x7f4\xabp\x00"\xc7\x85\x0b\x8cM\x0c\xb1GOx\xba\xdb\x9dy*\xc4]\x164%\xc73\xe8\xdb\xb6raB\xba+)b\x16"6\x90\xd6\xac\x1c\xcb\x1e#\xcb~!}V\xf2\xb2\xe3\xe8q&\x9bo\xeaJ\xdb\xc2\xd8\xda3.pNgD\x16\x05gri4&"\x13\xf6!\xdb\xbb\xae\xaf\xb6\x9bO#4\x05\xd3|\xf2\xcd\x9a 9 EC\xf4\x9d\xd7\x06L\x15\xc2 $\'\'\x98\xf5Z\x8b8\xcb)QE/\x1a~I\xe1K\xda{\xa0\x89\xc8<\xccFV\xc7:\xb9\xa6\xc0&\x17\xf13<{G\xe4X\x16j& \xef+\x85Z&\x03\xea}Uj]\x8d!\x15!\xcax\xfe\xd3\xffhlc\xb0\x10\xf9\x1d\xec\xa8\xf7F\xa0\xc4^U\xb1\xd0&\xf25Fe/\x113\x03f\xb9\xb6\xf4\x93w\x07\xa2sqK\x92\x81\x8b\x94\x8b[\xdaV\xab\xe1\xc9\x1e\xfd<\x1f^\xb2\xaf:\t\x878\xd7\xf9\x03}\xb7\xa5\xd4\xabIQ\xa2M\x8a\xab\x83n\xee\xc8\xa3\x82?C\xfb\x83\x97\xd92\xe6\xa0\x0c,bp\x96\x1bo@\x19H\xad\x8b\x92\xca+I\xf4\xf3\x038\xad\xaf\xd7e?\xbe\x06M\xd1\x18\x02\x90\x08\xc4\xe2Y\x06v\xe1\xd6D\x88\x93\x1e\xbb\x7f\x8e\xc7\xab\x0c\xae\x04\x89\x12\x8e\xaf\xee_g\xa8\x0c\xe4S\x8d\xb7\xea\xab\xe2\x8c\x0e\x93\\ei\x95\xc5^e\xad\xd5m\x04x\x7f\xc9z\xa0\x0eMQZ\xb0<\x98\xb0\xbe\xce\x8f\x83\x12\xe6\x8b\xb8V\xd9\xab.\x12,\x89\x91D\xe0\xce%\xb7|\xdd\x8e\xbb2c\xa1\xa2/\x8e\xd8\xaf\xc3)\xad{~z\xa3'
```

Comment: was ```output``` closed?

Comment: yes.And I have updated the code

Comment: are you absolutely sure you have a wave file?  I took a gander at that sequence of bytes, and the format doesn't fit the WAV specs.

Comment: Yes , I got a wave file

Comment: My code 
import wave


if __name__ == "__main__":

    audioFile = b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\x9fB\x86 ....... # Entire data


    filename = 'myfile.wav'
    output = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
    output.setparams((1, 2, 44100, 0, 'NONE', 'not compressed'))
    output.writeframes(audioFile)
    output.close()

Comment: sorry, but the audiofile isn't a WAV file.  it's a WEBM file.

Comment: then how to write this in wave file

Comment: save the file as a regular binary file and then following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064665/coverting-webm-to-wav-with-ffmpeg